# elasticsearch understanding threadpool

Tags: elasticsearch, threadpool

[Thread pool reference(official)](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-threadpool.html)

with respect to the above reference, I have a few questions

1. For search request: If my index has 2 shards, how many threads will it need
2. For bulk/write request: If my index has 2 shards, how many threads will it need
3. Does write & search request have dedicated threads? i.e no.of search request does not effect write threads/thread queue

   If a thread is writing to "Index_1" does it create a lock on the index? If I have a parallel search request on the same index, will it have to wait until the write operation is completed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inline answers

*1. For search request: If my index has 2 shards, how many threads will it need*?

**for each Primary shard, ES creates an individual thread.**

*2. bulk/write request: If my index has 2 shards, how many threads will it need*

**Same as first answer**

*3.Does write & search request have dedicated threads? i.e no.of search request does not affect write threads/thread queue*

**Yes, they have their own thread pools. search pool is for For count/search/suggest operations. write thread pool for For single-document index/delete/update and bulk requests.** More info on the same official link in the question.

Comment: thanks a lot, it answers my question, I have edited the question with a 4th point, could you please answer that as well.

Comment: @KaushikJ I appreciate but you should understand this is not a small question and generally you should ask these followup questions separate to make original question focused and to the point, what you are asking in now a border topic and isn't relvant to thread pool in ES.